# how to re-size image when responsive

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

I got this code from [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/) but it doesn't seem to work properly. Can any one tell me how to use this.

```html
<picture alt="description">
  <source src="small.jpg">
  <source src="medium.jpg" media="(min-width: 400px)">
  <source src="large.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
</picture>
```

my code

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <picture alt="description">  
      <source src="images/office-room.jpg">  
      <source src="medium.jpg" media="(min-width: 400px)">  
      <source src="large.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
  </picture>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you need more than just the html for this to work properly.  The article on css-tricks.com is pointing to this:  https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill as well.

Answer (score 1):

plz refer this one:

```
<style>
.fixed-ratio-resize { /* basic responsive img */
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* IE8 */
}
</style>

<img class="fixed-ratio-resize" src="students.jpg" alt=""/>
```

[DEMO](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/entry.php?293-3-Ways-to-Resize-Scale-Web-Images-in-Responsive-Design)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [srcset](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/) property to get away without using github picturefill

```
<img src="small.jpg" srcset="medium.jpg 1000w, large.jpg 2000w" alt="yah">
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like your using bootstrap with the col-sm-4 class

if so then you should just add this class to the image
img-responsive

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

so

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/office-room.jpg">  
</div>
```